# Format integer to be at least X digits by adding trailing zeroes

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

Is there a way to format an integer to be *at least* X digits by adding trailing zeroes? Such that with X being 4 I would get:

```
4 -> 4000
58 -> 5800
372 -> 3720
5432 -> 5432
12345678 -> 12345678
```

I know how to write a helper function to achieve this, just wondering if there is a built-in string formatting method to do the same.

Comment: This ok? `$"{value}0000".Substring(0, 4)`?

Comment: @Enigmativity for `12345678` that would return `1234`

Comment: You aren't formatting numbers, you are changing them, so of course there is nothing built-in for this.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay `Convert.ToInt32($"1{4:D4}")` will for example very easily let me turn 4 into 10004 so for some use cases there certainly are built-in functions that can be used to change numbers as one needs. Just wondering if there is also a method for my case.

Comment: Yes, but 10004 is a very different value to 4 though.

Comment: @user1151923 - Oh, yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int intValue = 20;
int x=4;
int.parse(intValue.ToString().PadRight('0',x))
```

Something like this should work

Check the syntax.

Comment: "Check the syntax" that's normally your job if you provide answers ;)
The approach is good but the correct syntax is : `string result = intValue.ToString().PadRight(4, '0');`

Comment: Noted. Thank You